# Implementing Same content in different View Controllers without creating extra View Controllers

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface

I have two screens which have half of the content same. I need to navigate from one view controller to another. Do I need to create both screen's content separately or there is an another way.

[image]

I hope I am clear with my question!

Comment: Try to refactor the part you want to have twice into a reusable View / ViewController and use it in both ViewControllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own UIView subclass an implement all filter ui there. Then use Your FilterView in both Controllers.

[Example](https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960)